# Efficient way of row-based calculation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-apply

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: class (0/1) and time (integer). I need to append a third column which will be the remaining time to get a class 1 row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,101], [1,104],
    [0,107], [0,110], [0,123],
    [1,156],
    [0,167]],
  columns=['class', 'time'])
```

- If a row has class 0; `diff` should be 0.
- If a row has class 1; `diff` should be the difference between its `time` and `time` of the first upcoming row that has class 0.

I can calculate it in a Lambda function:

```
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[ (df['time'] >= x[1]) & (df['class']==0)]['time'].iloc[0] - x[1], axis=1)
```

[image]

The expression `df[ (df['time'] >= x[1]) & (df['class']==0)]` is run for every row to get the next row with class 0. I believe it is not efficient for big dataframes.

What would be a more efficient way to calculate this?

Answer (score 4):

Not too much different from @Datanovice.

Use `where` to `NaN` the time for `df['class'] == 1`, then `bfill` to get the first `df['class']  == 0` value. This Series gets the correct 'time' to subtract regardless of class so we can do a normal subtraction.

```
df['Diff'] = df['time'].where(df['class'].eq(0)).bfill() - df['time']

   class  time  Diff
0      1   101   6.0
1      1   104   3.0
2      0   107   0.0
3      0   110   0.0
4      0   123   0.0
5      1   156  11.0
6      0   167   0.0
```

---

The Series created in the first step is:

```
df['time'].where(df['class'].eq(0)).bfill()
#0    107.0
#1    107.0
#2    107.0
#3    110.0
#4    123.0
#5    167.0
#6    167.0
#Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can chain boolean expressions to vectorise this.

First we find the first 0 after each group of `1`s

```
t = df[df['class'].ne(df['class'].shift()) & df['class'].eq(0)]['time']

print(t)
2    107
6    167
Name: time, dtype: int64

#then we assign a column and back fill it.

df = df.assign(Diff = t).bfill()
```

and finally the conditional to do our sum and calculate the 0 `Diff` values.

```
df['Diff'] = np.where(df['class'].eq(1),df['Diff'] - df['time'],0)


print(df)

   class  time  Diff
0      1   101   6.0
1      1   104   3.0
2      0   107   0.0
3      0   110   0.0
4      0   123   0.0
5      1   156  11.0
6      0   167   0.0
```